# Xcode - Header files without Classes and Variables colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

All the Colors of the Classes and Variables in the Header files of a specific project is missing.
I tried to delete the Derived Data, but nothing changed and also open & close XCode.

[image]

Comment: This happens to me many times a day. Usually resolved by building but sometimes I have to close Xcode and reopen.

Comment: Upper camelcase? This 'aint Java.  : )

Comment: In this example everything looks fine but it could happen because of missing bracket. If restarting Xcode doesn't help try inspecting your code.